# Регулярное исключение

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

**Дано**: любая строка содержащая любые символы (**asdfaslcvbieubcasku**)

**Нужно**: заменить в строке все символы кроме последних четырех (аналог сокрытия номера банковской карты)

**Как я это делаю**:  Я хочу научится применять RegExp, у меня в голове это выглядит примерно так *`/.+[^(.{4})$]/`* (найти все, [кроме^условие]), но оно не работает так как надо =(.

**Результат**: Как мне правильно составить исключающий паттерн (Найти что-то, кроме) в виде RegExp?

***UDP***: Да я знаю что можно найти 4 символа с конца *`/(.{4})$/`*, но для решения моей задачи "в одну строку" мне хотелось бы уметь правильно пользоваться исключением RegExp

Comment: Что-то вроде `s.replace(/.(?=.{4})/g, 'x')` ([демо](https://regex101.com/r/Agce6g/1))?

Comment: Вам нужны lookahead positive assertions `(?=`

Comment: Да Wiktor Ваш вариант тоже нужное мне решение благодарю!

Comment: Alexey, спасибо за напровление 'куда копать'!

Comment: В следующий раз обязательно добавьте ожидаемый результат в вопрос, так бы я опубликовал ответ. Вы уверены, что вам нужен именно `.*(?=.{4})`? По-моему, эта регулярка ну никак не подходит, см. [здесь](https://regex101.com/r/GZeR72/3). Будет произведено 2 замены. Вам нужно, скорее всего, 1 или много.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Вы абсолютно правы, однако этот наводящий пример я адаптировал под Ваш комментарий "Что-то вроде s.replace(/.(?=.{4})/g, 'x')" Который я увидел чуточку позже =). Однако я считаю что оба варианта правельные так как основой вопроса все же является сама регулярна исключающая 4 последних элемента.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С javascript плохо знаком, поэтому укажу регулярное выражение, а вы его сами адаптируйте:

```
/.*(?=.{4})
```

[Пример](https://regex101.com/r/GZeR72/2)

Более подробно почитать про просмотр вперед и назад можно на [Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F).

Comment: Да именно это было и нужно, спасибо!